# Have parent category contain only one post?

Tags: categories, query-posts

```
Projects <-contains basic info about projects 
-Proj1 <-detailed info about proj1 
-Proj2 <-detailed info about proj2 
-Proj3 <-detailed info about proj3
```

I have a post attributed to the parent category 'Projects', and I want only that post to be seen when 'Projects' is clicked. By default, each of the subcategories' posts are being shown when I click 'Projects.' Is there a way to change this default setting, so that no posts from subcategories 'Proj1,' 'Proj2,' and 'Proj3' are seen in 'Projects'?

I was referred to a plugin called [Cat Lists Plus](http://www.technokinetics.com/plugins/cat-lists-plus/), but this completely eliminates the parent category link. (This has also not been released yet.)

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the posts query by using the `pre_get_posts` filter, and passing the parameter `category__in`.

In order to do that, put the following code in your theme's functions.php:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'get_parent_category_posts' );

function get_parent_category_posts($query){

   if (is_category() && is_main_query()){
       $curr_cat = get_query_var('cat');
       $query->set('category__in', array($curr_cat));
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried that and then clicked on 'Projects,' but I am now seeing the subcategories AND the post associated with 'Projects.' Do you know how I can remove the subcategories' posts?

Comment: @mdegges: That's what the code is supposed to do... Maybe the condition is wrong? Can you confirm that the code is actually executed? You can either run the code in debugger mode to see if it gets to those lines, or write `echo` statements inside the condition and see if they are written on your screen.